# Make NSArrayController fetch after background operation completes

Tags: cocoa, concurrency

I have a subclass of an NSArrayController linked to a core data model. In one of the methods I call

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(someLongExpensiveOperation:) withObject:obj];
```

which imports a ton of core data objects in the background.

The problem is, unless I manually add a fetch button on the interface and click it after the import operation completes, the array controller doesn't update itself to reflect the new data model. Any ideas on how to force array controller to update?

**EDIT:**

Turned out I also had some concurrency issues as NSManagedObjectContext is not suppose to be thread-safe. Had to account for that as well and then it started working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call prepareContent at the end of your someLongExpensiveOperation: method.

Comment: Yeah sure. Make sure that you lock and unlock your NSManagedObjectContext as well while inserting new objects in the background.

Comment: I tried calling the NSArrayController's fetch: method at the end of the someLongExpensiveOperation:, but that doesn't seem to do anything useful and manually pressing button with action=fetch: was still required. What's the difference between fetch: and prepareContent anyways?

Comment: Does fetch: use prepareContent in the background?